# Update User Data in Azure Active Directory Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

Im trying to make a Java Application in which a user can login in to his Activer Directory and update his account info like phonenumber or display name, password, etc.

im able to authenticate the user but however i cant seem to find anything on updating the data. can anyone guide me through this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On work around you can use the **Microsoft Graph Rest API to update the user**.

Not all properties can be updated by Member or Guest users with their default permissions without Administrator roles. [Compare member and guest default permissions to see properties they can manage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#compare-member-and-guest-default-permissions).

**Note:** **Your personal Microsoft account must be tied to an AAD tenant to update your profile with the User.ReadWrite delegated permission on a personal Microsoft account.**

**Example : Update properties of the signed-in user**

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();
User user = new User();
LinkedList<String> businessPhonesList = new LinkedList<String>();
businessPhonesList.add("+1 425 555 0109");
user.businessPhones = businessPhonesList;
user.officeLocation = "18/2111";

graphClient.me()
    .buildRequest()
    .patch(user);
```

For more information and examples refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java):

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me check it

Comment: Sure, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you